# X11 forwarding: `xclock` works but not `cmake-gui`

Tags: ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I am connecting (ssh) to my host (Mac) from my client (Windows) machine. I have X11 forwarding active.

Now, running `xclock` on my host opens up the clock gui window on my client as expected, but running `cmake-gui` does not. I can see the application gui open up on my host (through teamviewer), but it isn't shown on my client.

I was able to make it work with WSL but somehow it's not working for my iMac as host.

I can provide more details if needed. Let me know how.

Comment: Is cmake-gui an x11 program osx?

Comment: @matt Does it need to be compiled as such? I though X11 can forward any GUI application.

Comment: To my knowledge it has to be displayed through the running xserver.